# Are there any specific requirements to enable "fast-start" progressive download with webm and ogg codecs?

Tags: video, ogg, webm, progressive-download

I know that with `mp4`, the `moov atom` must be placed at the beginning of the file to enable progressive downloading. That can be done by enabling "faststart" when creating the file.

I'm curious if there are any similar requirements when dealing with `webm` or `ogg` files, or are they "progressive download ready" by default?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Due to the way they are constructed, WebM (Matroska) and Ogg files **do not** have any fast-start remuxing requirements to make them suitable for progressive downloading.

Comment: Are you saying in other words that they are able by default to facilitate progressive download?

Comment: That's right. Not all containers are created equally. Ogg and WebM have characteristics which allow them to be downloaded progressively without any post-processing step. At least, I have never seen any demand for a 'webm-faststart' or 'ogg-faststart' utility (I'm the original author of the 'qt-faststart' utility that is in wide use for post-processing MP4 files for progressive download).

Comment: Mike, thanks a bunch for your help. Would you mind posting a link to your utility?

Comment: This seems to be the homepage for qt-faststart: http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/ ... it comes with FFmpeg and Libav, and there are various ports to other languages. One should work for you.